# Dupehammer does not include flagged duplicate suggestions

Tags: bug, flags, dupehammer

If a 3k user votes to close a question A as a dupe of B and then another user dupehammers to C, both B and C are listed in the close notice.

However, when a user with <3k rep flags as a duplicate of B, and then A is dupehammered to C, it's only closed as a duplicate of C. IMHO the former behaviour is desired for flags as well. The problem is compounded by the autogenerated flag comment being deleted when the question is dupehammered, so that a potentially useful comment is lost to the OP.

Thankfully, the linked questions list still includes question B.

Note that this is only about dupehammered closures, where the list of questions can be edited by the hammer-wielder. So, they can edit in B if they find it useful, but IMHO it should be the other way around: B should be included by default and edited out if necessary. I think B may likely be of some use to the OP, so removing all obvious links to it but keeping it in the sidebar is a bad move.

An example: https://askubuntu.com/posts/998931/timeline

Comment: There are two separate issues here now: one is B now showing in the dupe list after closure, and the other is the comment with B is deleted. Better split it up. (Otherwise both will likely be "lost".)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard do you mean "one is B no**t** showing in the dupe list after closure" or "one is B now showing in the linked list after closure"?

Comment: Oops yeah, meant "not"

Answer (score 5):

I disagree. That's surely not a bug, and I don't want such a feature.

User with 15 reputation **should not directly affect the closure**, as they're most likely not familiar enough with the site yet.

Most such user can do is flag, i.e. suggest a duplicate, then users with enough reputation see the suggestion and can either use it, or not.

Also, this isn't related to the dupe hammer. If 5 ordinary high rep users will all choose C, then B won't be listed as well. The list contains only the questions chosen by actual close votes.

Comment: In that case the comment shouldn't be autodeleted. *That* would be a bug.

Comment: @muru interesting, that might be a bug indeed. But that's far from what you posted in the question here. You can still change it now I guess, I'll remove the answer and 2 downvotes aren't fatal yet.

Comment: Given the comment deletion behaviour, and that the question still shows up in the linked questions list, I reasonably concluded that the flagged candidate is also being considered by the system somehow. That's why I picked this as the bug to be reported.

Comment: So, sorry, I don't intend to change the bug being reported when there are two implemented factors in favour and only opinion against.

Comment: The flagged candidates are indeed "considered", they show up when other users choose to close.

Comment: I meant post-closure, of course.

Comment: @muru again, why should they? Why would SE give such power to low rep users?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "such power". It's a dupehammered closure. The list of questions can be edited if necessary. So to me it seems reasonable to include such targets by default rather than not include them - removing only if the target is actively harmful.

Comment: Well, I disagree. Let the team (and community) decide the fate of this, nothing is final yet. :)